# dy/dx implicity

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Question: Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ implicity if $x=\tan(xy)$.

So far, I have used implicit differentiation on both sides of the equation and ended up with two different answers. The first one was a bit more work than the second one.

My first answer is $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\cos^2{xy}(1-y\sec^2{xy})}{x}$.

My second answer is $1=y\sec^2{xy}+x\sec^2{xy}\frac{dy}{dx}$
therefore $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1 - y\sec^2{xy}}{x\sec^2{xy}}$.

The wording of the question is what's really throwing me off. Which of these is the correct answer, or are they both wrong?
Your help is always appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Your answers are identical:
$$
\frac{1}{\sec^{2}(xy)} = \cos^{2}(xy).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$F=\tan(xy)-x=0$$ So $$F'_x=y \sec ^2(x y)-1$$ $$ F'_y=x \sec ^2(x y)$$ and $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=\frac{\cos ^2(x y) \left(1-y \sec ^2(x y)\right)}{x}=\frac{\cos ^2(x y)-y}{x}$$ and this is exactly your second answer (before the last simplification).

Comment: Why could you treat x or y as constant? What method is this?

Comment: This is the implicit function theorem  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem